# Run a script in parallel until another one finishes

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I have 2 python scripts A.py and B.py

I'd like to run both of them in parallel, but I'd like to keep running B.py multiple times successively in parallel until A.py finishes

something like :

```
A.py &
while A.py not finished :
     B.py &
end while
```

I'm very bad at shell scripting, can someone explain me how to do this ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

python A.py &

while [[ $(jobs -pr) ]]; do
    python B.py
done
```

`jobs -pr` lists the process IDs (`-p`) of running jobs (`-r`). If the output is empty, the backgrounds command has finished.

Comment: Thank you dan for your answer, it works perfectly :) !

Comment: @AydinAbiar Happy to help. If you have some time, can you please have a look at this guide: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)